# Delete old events in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

While testing my iOS app, I used some event names that I have since removed and never actually deployed.

Now, my Events Overview page in Google Analytics is cluttered with old event category/action/label names. (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/events)

Is there any way to remove them?

Answer (score 4):

To Delete a view
It's Important to keep in mind:
 A view is permanently deleted 35 days after being moved to the Trash Can. Once deleted, the view is gone, and we are not be able to retrieve any historical data or reinstate the reports. This includes any setting and configuration preferences, like Goals and user permissions, but does not include data saved at the property or account level.
You must have Edit permission to move a view to the Trash Can. To move a view to the Trash Can:

Sign in to your Analytics account.
Select the Admin tab and navigate to the view you wish to delete.
In the VIEW column, click View Settings.
Click Move view to Trash Can.
Click Move view to Trash Can in the confirmation message.
[image: account property and view menus]